# Is UPDATE with WHERE and JOIN atomic in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

For example, something like:

```
UPDATE table_A
SET col_1 TO ... (some values)
WHERE exists (select col_2 from table_A join table_B On table_A.col_3 = table_B.col3)
```

Here I wish to update col_1 in table_A only when the result of joining table A and B on col3 has something. 
Is the operation atomic? If someone modified table A or B at the same time, and the join result becomes invalid (e.g. causes `exists` to return false), will the update still perform?
If I do the following in a postgresql function instead, will this be atomic?

```
Create function atomic_update(... --parameters)
...
BEGIN
select col_2 from table_A join table_B On table_A.col_3 = table_B.col3 into exists;
if exists
    -- do update
    update table_A where ...
else
    -- raise exception
END
...
```

Comment: Your definition of "atomic" is unusual. Commonly it means "cannot be split up", but you mean "is isolated from concurrent data modifications". No, it isn't. But your query is doing something entirely different from what you think: the subquery is not correlated to the main query, so the exists clause is probably equivalent to writing `WHERE TRUE`.

Comment: Every statement you run is "atomic". However, your UPDATE is not safe for concurrent updates which is something different than "atomic". But I think you are probably looking for `update table_a  set ... from table_b where table_A.col_3 = table_B.col3`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so if there's another transaction modifying tableA and tableB at the same time such that there's no col_3 values matching, what happens to the update operation?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm still rather confused, can you explain further why "the exists clause is probably equivalent to writing WHERE TRUE"?

Comment: Well, if there is *any* row in `table_A` and `table_B` with the same `col3`, the `EXISTS` clause will result in `TRUE`.  For all rows in `table_A`.